# Effective bound of Fourier coefficients of weakly modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Assuming $$f=\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty c_f(n/m)e^{{2\pi inz}/{m}},\quad (n_0\in\mathbb Z, m\in\mathbb Z_{\geq1})$$ is a weakly modular form with weight $k$ and congruence subgroup $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N),\Gamma_1(N)$ or $\Gamma(N)$. Is there an effective upper bound on the absolute values of the coefficients $|c_f(n)|$ of $f$? In other words, can an upper bound be expressed in terms of $k$ and $N$ after they are determined?

This question arose while studying the paper **[1]**, referring to equations (65)-(69). I have been struggling to understand how equations (65)-(69) were derived, as the author did not provide detailed explanations. If someone could provide some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

All comments are welcome.

**[1]** *Viazovska, Maryna S.*, [**The sphere packing problem in dimension 8**](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2017.185.3.7), Ann. Math. (2) 185, No. 3, 991-1015 (2017). [ZBL1373.52025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.52025).

Comment: To clarify, by weakly modular do you mean meromorphic on the extended upper half plane + modular transformation laws?  Do you have any control on poles?

Comment: @Kimball. Poles can only occur at cusps.

Comment: Then you can multiply by cusp forms to get something holomorphic, and use Deligne's bound.